# MacOs thinks .Net Core Project Folder is a .app folder

Tags: .net, macos

Got something very strange happening. I have a .net core project folder with .net core c# code in it.

When I look at the folder on my Mac it has a no entry symbol super imposed over it. If I click on it MacOs says I can't open the application because it may be damaged or incomplete.

It insists in the UI that the folder has a .app extension but using the terminal it definitely does not!

This is really annoying me. I have tried google to see what file MacOS is looking for to make the OS think this is a .app folder and can't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically don't make your folder end with .Service in macos!!

Crazy!

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15298/why-does-os-x-prevent-access-to-a-folder-if-it-ends-with-the-word-service/15303